# Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to use netty with native Kqueue Sockets in my Macbook with Mac OS Sierra. 
I followed the netty native transport [guide](http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html)

I still see this error in the logs:

```html
       52 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader  - Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64 in java.library.path
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
     at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

and then:

```html
55 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader  - netty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64 cannot be loaded from java.libary.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /var/folders/95/w43w134s6lg14g8584qpwcmh0000gn/T
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64 in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
 at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
 at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
 at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
```

I am using maven and this is my pom:

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.19.Final</version>
            <classifier>${os.detected.name}-${os.detected.arch}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
....

  <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
```

This is what intellij lists as imported libs:
[libnetty_transport_native_kqueue_x86_64.jnilib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FHRN.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note these are just debug messages as it tries different loading-strategies. You can check if it was able to load the native code by using `KQueue.isAvailable()` after initialization is done.